# UTF-8 is not working for TextArea contents

Tags: c#, unicode, httpwebrequest, textarea, jspx

I'm interacting a website using `HttpRequest`s in C#
I can read the page contents but when i try to post some information back to the server, everything works correctly but not about the value of `TextArea`s  in the page...
The text I'm trying to set for them is in  **Persian (Farsi)**   and the page I'm receiving is set for **Windows-1256** encoding...

The problem is that the content of the `textarea` is not shown as I expect in Farsi!

**Update:** here is the code I use to send  the request:

```
public static string PostMultipart(string URL, List<RequestParameterInfo> parameters, List<string> cookies, string referer, string acceptLanguage, string acceptCharset, object KeepAliveValue)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL));
   var boundary = "---------------------------7dc283270344";
   var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary);

   foreach (var item in parameters)
   {
      var prefixBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\n");
      var itemBytes = item.ToBytes();
      var postfixBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\n--" + boundary);

      var startIndex = messageBytes.Length;
      Array.Resize<byte>(ref messageBytes, messageBytes.Length + itemBytes.Length + prefixBytes.Length + postfixBytes.Length);

      prefixBytes.CopyTo(messageBytes, startIndex);
      itemBytes.CopyTo(messageBytes, startIndex + prefixBytes.Length);
      postfixBytes.CopyTo(messageBytes, startIndex + prefixBytes.Length + itemBytes.Length);
     }

     var lastPostfixBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--");
     var startIndex2 = messageBytes.Length;
     Array.Resize<byte>(ref messageBytes, messageBytes.Length + lastPostfixBytes.Length);
     lastPostfixBytes.CopyTo(messageBytes, startIndex2);




     request.Headers.Clear();
     request.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*";
     request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");
     request.ContentLength = messageBytes.Length;

     request.Referer = referer;
     request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)";
     request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
     request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
     request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, acceptLanguage);

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(acceptCharset))
         request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, acceptCharset);

     if (KeepAliveValue is Boolean)
         request.KeepAlive = (bool)KeepAliveValue;
     else
         request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, (string)KeepAliveValue);

     request.Expect = null;

     request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
     foreach (var item in cookies)
         request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(URL), item);

     request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
     request.Method = "POST";

     using (var strm = request.GetRequestStream())
     {
         strm.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
     }

     string resPage = "";
     using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
     {
         using (StreamReader srResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             resPage = srResponse.ReadToEnd();
         }
     }

     return resPage;
 }
```

Comment: how do you post to the server?

Comment: I tried many ways... including converting the text to UTF-8 and putting that in the request data package

Answer (score 0):

Change your Form element to use the correct encoding:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="Windows-1256" />
```

or `<form accept-charset="utf-8" />`

**Update:**

```
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset: utf-8; boundary=" + boundary;
```

Comment: i'm using `HttpWebRequest`!

Comment: ok that wasn't clear before update! try `request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset: utf-8; boundary=" + boundary;`

Comment: It wasn't the answer... but anyway I found it!